# How do I use a template type of an outer class as a field in an inner class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, field

I have a C++ file that looks like the following.

```
    // used for text debugging
    #include 
    #include 
    //#include 
    #include 

    // stl includes
    #include 
    #include 
    #include 



    // fast fixed size memory allocator, used for fast node memory management
    #include "fsa.h"

    // Fixed size memory allocator can be disabled to compare performance
    // Uses std new and delete instead if you turn it off
    #define USE_FSA_MEMORY 1

    // disable warning that debugging information has lines that are truncated
    // occurs in stl headers
    #pragma warning( disable : 4786 )

    // The AStar search class. UserState is the users state space type
    template class AStarSearch {

    public:
        // data

        enum {
            SEARCH_STATE_NOT_INITIALISED,
            SEARCH_STATE_SEARCHING,
            SEARCH_STATE_SUCCEEDED,
            SEARCH_STATE_FAILED,
            SEARCH_STATE_OUT_OF_MEMORY,
            SEARCH_STATE_INVALID
        };

        // A node represents a possible state in the search
        // The user provided state type is included inside this type

    public:

        class Node {
        public:

            Node *parent; // used during the search to record the parent of successor nodes
            Node *child; // used after the search for the application to view the search in reverse

            float g; // cost of this node + it's predecessors (cost so far)
            float h; // heuristic estimate of distance to goal (heuristic estimate)
            float f; // sum of cumulative cost of predecessors and self and heuristic (costSoFar + heuristic estimate).

            Node() :
                    parent(0), child(0), g(0.0f), h(0.0f), f(0.0f) {
            }

             UserState m_UserState;
        };

        // For sorting the heap the STL needs compare function that lets us compare
        // the f value of two nodes

        class HeapCompare_f {
        public:

            bool operator()(const Node *x, const Node *y) const {
                // The total heuristic estimation compare.
                return x->f > y->f;
            }
        };

    public:
        // methods

        // constructor just initialises private data
        AStarSearch(int MaxNodes = 1000) ;

        // call at any time to cancel the search and free up all the memory
        void CancelSearch() ;

        // Set Start and goal states
        void SetStartAndGoalStates(UserState &Start, UserState &Goal) ;

        // Advances search one step 
        unsigned int SearchStep() ;

        // User calls this to add a successor to a list of successors
        // when expanding the search frontier
        bool AddSuccessor(UserState &State) ;

        // Free the solution nodes
        // This is done to clean up all used Node memory when you are done with the
        // search
        void FreeSolutionNodes() ;

        // Functions for traversing the solution

        // Get start node
        UserState *GetSolutionStart() ;

        // Get next node
        UserState *GetSolutionNext() ;

        // Get end node
        UserState *GetSolutionEnd() ;

        // Step solution iterator backwards
        UserState *GetSolutionPrev() ;

        // For educational use and debugging it is useful to be able to view
        // the open and closed list at each step, here are two functions to allow that.

        UserState *GetOpenListStart() ;

        UserState *GetOpenListStart(float &f, float &g, float &h) ;

        UserState *GetOpenListNext() ;

        UserState *GetOpenListNext(float &f, float &g, float &h) ;

        UserState *GetClosedListStart() ;

        UserState *GetClosedListStart(float &f, float &g, float &h) ;

        UserState *GetClosedListNext() ;

        UserState *GetClosedListNext(float &f, float &g, float &h) ;

        // Get the number of steps

        int GetStepCount() ;

        void EnsureMemoryFreed() ;

    private:
        // methods

        // This is called when a search fails or is cancelled to free all used
        // memory 
        void FreeAllNodes() ;

        // This call is made by the search class when the search ends. A lot of nodes may be
        // created that are still present when the search ends. They will be deleted by this 
        // routine once the search ends
        void FreeUnusedNodes() ;

        // Node memory management
        Node *AllocateNode() ;

        void FreeNode(Node *node) ;

    private:
        // data

        // Heap (simple vector but used as a heap, cf. Steve Rabin's game gems article)
        std::vector m_OpenList;

        // Closed list is a vector.
        std::vector m_ClosedList;

        // Successors is a vector filled out by the user each type successors to a node
        // are generated
        std::vector m_Successors;

        // State
        unsigned int m_State;

        // Counts steps
        int m_Steps;

        // Start and goal state pointers
        Node *m_Start;
        Node *m_Goal;

        // A pointer used for supporting iterate through the solution chain.
        Node *m_CurrentSolutionNode;

    #if USE_FSA_MEMORY
        // Memory
        FixedSizeAllocator m_FixedSizeAllocator;
    #endif

        //Debug : need to keep these two iterators around
        // for the user Dbg functions
        typename std::vector::iterator iterDbgOpen;
        typename std::vector::iterator iterDbgClosed;

        // debugging : count memory allocation and free's
        int m_AllocateNodeCount;

        bool m_CancelRequest;

    };
```

I can't compile it; the error I get is:

> Field has incomplete type 'UserState'

How can I get this resolved?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? It compiles fine by GCC :  http://ideone.com/8HBmhH

Comment: Also, there is no member named as `Field`. So maybe the error is coming from some other class, or the posted code is not the exact same code which gives you this compilation error.

Comment: Is the template argument provided for `T` complete at the point where `A` is instantiated?

Comment: Hi, Now I'm using Xcode and LLVM compiler version 4.1

Comment: Hi ,the error message is "aField has incomplete type 'T'", sorry ,wrong typing

Comment: Hi, James ,I dont understand because I was a newbee for C++, how to determine the T is complete? As my thought it is just a type ,and do not need complete specified or implemented. I dont know if it is right.

Answer (score 3):

You can just the template argument of the outer class without any further ado. However, when you instantiate `A<X>` with some type `X` you need to make sure that the type `X` is complete when you access the inner type:

```
struct X;
A<X>::B a0; // ERROR: X is incomplete

struct X {};
A<X>::B a1; // OK: X is complete
```

Comment: Hi ,Dietmar: Actually I'm just define a header file, and the inner class using the type parameter of outer class as the type of field "aField", I'm not start initialize any Class, thank you.

Comment: @user1099102: I doubt that you don't use the inner class! Please post a short but complete example program demonstrating the problem if you insist that you don't instantiate the class template and access its nested type.

Comment: Uh ,I guess that the trouble come from other place ,and not the header file ,I just copied the source from XCode to Eclipse and just leave the header file, and the error has gone....,thank you guys ,I will check the code again.

Comment: template<class T> class A{

public:
 class B{
  T a;
 };

};

Comment: Hi ,Dietmar, you are right, because XCode locate the error in header file ,then I guess the trouble cause by this header but actually it caused by other files. The header file has no problem, thanks! :)

Comment: @user1099102: the code in your last comment does *not* produce the above error! It just defines a template but doesn't use it. The compiler isn't allowed to check that it would work other than that the source code needs to be well-formed (which it is).

Comment: Hi ,Dietmar : I will paste all codes in origin article, please help me :)

Comment: @user1099102: *All* this code is needed to reproduce the problem? (not to mention that it is still incomplete in the form currently posted) I very much doubt that it can't be reduced further! Put differently: Your job: produce a minimal example showing the problem when cut&pasted into a source file. My job: explain the error made. The current code is neither complete nor minimal!

Comment: Sorry , I posted but the some text stripped off.